# How to run scenarios in calabash android without reset

Tags: calabash-android

I want to run a feature file containing different szenarios. **Without** a reset after each szenario.

I tried to run this test by command line with 'RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS' tag.

```
RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=0 calabash-android run
```

doesn't work.

I tried to uncomment ('#') some lines in app_life_cycle_hooks.rb file:

```
require 'calabash-android/management/adb'
require 'calabash-android/operations'

Before do |scenario|
 #start_test_server_in_background
end

After do |scenario|
 if scenario.failed?
 screenshot_embed
end
#shutdown_test_server
end
```

doesn't work.

I tried to uncomment die following lines in app_installation_hooks.rb

```
uninstall_apps
install_app(ENV['TEST_APP_PATH'])
install_app(ENV['APP_PATH'])
```

doesn't work.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong hooks file.

Comment: it would be useful to know the file and the line which i have to edit.

Comment: It will depend on the files in your projects support folder.  You can have multiple before hooks, so you'll need to look through all of them to find what's reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

I removed (by comment) this line in app_installation_hooks.rb

```
uninstall_apps
```

and this lines in app_life_cycle_hooks.rb

```
start_test_server_in_background
shutdown_test_server
```

I created a file start_server.rb in /step_definitions defined a custom step:

```
Given /^I started the server$/ do
 start_test_server_in_background
end
```

which I used in my first scenario

```
Scenario: S1
Given I started the server
...
```

I run this by my .sh script (in shell) including the run statement

```
calabash-android run PATH_TO_APK
```